# Sharesheet in Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack, android-jetpack-compose

How do I share content using Android's Sharesheet in Jetpack Compose?

[image]

Comment: Can you start an activity inside a `@Composable` method?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Inside a `@Composable` you can use an `Intent` in a *standard* way.

Something like:

```
val sendIntent: Intent = Intent().apply {
    action = Intent.ACTION_SEND
    putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "This is my text to send.")
    type = "text/plain"
}
val shareIntent = Intent.createChooser(sendIntent, null)
val context = LocalContext.current

Button(onClick = {
    context.startActivity(shareIntent)
}){
    Text("Share")
}
```

[image]

Comment: Ah...that should have been obvious ‍♂️ I guess with everything, including navigation with compose navigation, being so different, I assumed there was a new/different way... thanks

Comment: Can you update your solution in order to have the same icon as in the question?

Comment: Can you please give me idea how to handle the text into my `TextFieald` compose I mean from another app to my app??

Answer (score 1):

In **JetPack compose** Sharesheet you can call the below function by passing the **context**. (**If app is not published you can omit store url**)

```
    fun shareAppPlayStoreUrl(context: Context){
    val sendIntent: Intent = Intent().apply {
        action = Intent.ACTION_SEND
        putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Check out this awesome app\n "+"https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id="+context.applicationInfo.packageName)
        type = "text/plain"
    }
    val shareIntent = Intent.createChooser(sendIntent, null)
    context.startActivity(shareIntent)
}
```